# Dynamically allocate Struct array in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I have searched a lot of topics.
But none of them really match the answer I want.

I want to allocate an array of struct type dynamically.

But, I failed and get the error 
***"Error 3 error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type"*** during the compiling.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Term{
    int row;
    int column;
    int value;
};

int main(void){
    int size;
    printf("Enter how many non-zero value you want to transpose:");
    scanf_s("%d",&size);
    struct Term *termA = (struct Term *)malloc((sizeof(struct Term))*(size+1));
    termA[0].value = size;      
}
```

**After some help, the correct code is provided as below:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Term{
    int row;
    int column;
    int value;
};

int main(void){
    int size;
    struct Term *termA;
    printf("Enter how many non-zero value you want to transpose:");
    scanf_s("%d",&size);
    termA = (struct Term *)malloc((sizeof(struct Term))*(size+1));
    termA[0].value = size;      
}
```

Comment: `int size; struct Term *termA;`... `termA = (struct Term *)malloc((sizeof(struct Term))*(size+1));` also remove extra `}`

Comment: Unrelated, you have an extra `}` in the source. And lose the `typedef` in front of `typedef struct Term{`, it's pointless and you should have been at-least-warned about it by your compiler.

Comment: Wow, It works. Why?

Comment: It is because you are using the C compiler compliant C89. It does not allow a mix of the declarations (and definitions) and (excution) code.

Comment: Thank you, @BLUEPIXY. You are awesome.

Comment: @EugeneLiu: why are you using the `typedef` keyword here?

Comment: @babon : Although I didn't use another name to define the struct "Term". I still like to keep it. It doesn't impact the original question.

Comment: @EugeneLiu: I did not say it impacts the original question. I wanted to point out that it was unnecessary.